# QGIS 3: About "topological editing" and 'avoid intersection"

Tags: qgis, editing, qgis-3

Where are those two editing options ? They used to be with the snapping options but apparently they have been moved somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found it... With QGIS 3 the "topoligical editing" and 'avoid intersection" options are in the "project" menu within the well called "snapping options", item that used to be in the "preference" menu in QGIS 2.x.
Note that you can still find some "snapping parameters" in Preference > Options > Editing > Snapping
Probably why i was confused.

Comment: To complete the answer, note that you need to enable advanced settings (same drop down as "All layers" and "Active layers" to get "avoid overlap" checkbox available.